# php failed signature verification and may have been tampered with

Tags: windows-8.1, php, iis

I have been unable to install any version of PHP on Windows/IIS via Web Platform Installer 5.0 running on Windows 8.1. I have tried several different versions of PHP: 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6. Each time, it downloads and appears to be installing, but then after awhile it gives this message: "...failed signature verification and may have been tampered with". This makes no sense. It's a MS installer pulling from a location that MS designated.

How can I install PHP on my Win8.1 PC, linked to IIS? On Windows 7 this was a breeze and worked great. Is there a way to install PHP without going through this silly Web Platform Installer?